# Any possible way to get the value from form1 to form2 before submitting form2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two forms in single page.Is there a possible way to get the selected value from form1 before submiting the form2.So that I can insert two values(selected value from form1 and input box value from form2) in one table as single row.Need help

**HTML:**

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><select name="type">
<option value="">Select Type</option>
<option value="val1" selected="selected">val1</option>
<option value="val2">val2</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<form name="form2" id="form2" method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="test1"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="go" value="go" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can get the selected value but when do you want to do this when submitting form 1 when submiting form 2 when select a value ?

Comment: It's not possible to get the value using html post form methods. I think you could simply use single form and in that itself you could use those two fields and thus you can save two values to tables

Comment: I should get the selected value from form1 before submitting form2. Because the table is only for form2.I need to insert both form1 and 2 values when I press submit button in form2

Comment: @Hoja.M.A: If its not possible by html post,please suggest me using script

Comment: Check my answer bellow this is what you want to do ?

Comment: @vas_bar_code: Check my answer I hope it helps

Comment: Please check my reply below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. just use a hidden field in form two and when ever the select box changes assign the changedvalue to the hidden field

    $('#selectbox').on('change',function() {
      $('#hiddenfield').val($('#selectbox').val());//HIDDEN FIELD PLACED IN FORM 2
    });

by this method you could get the form 1 value to form 2 submit.
```

You Could use this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/jw3y9ky7/

Comment: I tried,but not working. please check the link [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cudofekuvo/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @vas_bar_code: you forgot name attribute bro. give name to your hidden field you'll get the value

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#form2').submit(function(){
    var valueSelected = jQuery("select[name='type']").val();
    //Do what you want
});
```

You can use the valueSelected variable to do what you want.

Comment: you forgot the `.val()`: `jQuery("select[name='type']").val()` - and you don't need to add the `option` to your selector. the `.val()` of `select` always returns the value of its selected `option`.